# Calculating gradient, how to do this?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Given $f(x,y)$, a function that has continuous partial derivatives in
> every point.
>
> such that $\nabla f(0,-18)=-2i+3j$
>
> We define a new function $g(x,y)=f(xy+x^2,xy-y^2)$ calculate $\nabla
>  g(3,-3)$

How I tried to solve this?
I need to find:
$$\nabla g(3,-3) = g_x'(3,-3)i+g_y'(3,-3)j=f(xy+x^2,xy-y^2)_x'(3,-3)i+f(xy+x^2,xy-y^2)_y'(3,-3)j$$

and I got stuck here; I don't have f to calculate the partial directive for it...

Comment: Try substituting $x=-3$ and $y=3$.

Comment: I've posted my response as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify notation, let us define $u= xy+x^2$, $v=xy-y^2$, so that:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=y+2x  ,\quad \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=y
$$

Then, using the chain rule, since $g(x,y)=f(u,v)$:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Now, if $q=(x,y)=(3,-3)$ we have $p=(u,v)=(0,-18)$, and we already know:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right|_p =-2  , \quad 
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\right|_p =3
$$
Also we can compute from above:
$$
\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_q =3  ,\quad \left. \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right|_q=-3
$$

Then,
$$\left.\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right|_p=-2 \cdot 3+ 3 \cdot (-3)=-15 $$

Can you repeat the operation with $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ ?

Comment: I didn't understand what came after Now, if =(,)

Comment: @Daniel98 You substitute $x, y$ on the definition of $u, v$

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the **multivariable chain rule** (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3724367/695196)) which states that given a function $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and a function $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\nabla (f \circ h) = \left(h'\right)^T \cdot \left(\nabla f \circ h\right)
$$
where "$\cdot$" represents matrix multiplication.

---

In our case, we see that if we define $h(x,y) = (xy+x^2,xy-y^2)$ then it follows from the definition of $g$ that
$$g(x,y) = (f \circ h)(x,y)= f(xy+x^2,xy-y^2) \tag{1}$$
which means that calculating $\nabla g(3,-3)$ is equal to calculating $\nabla (f \circ h)(3,-3) $.

Now, by definition, we know that
$$
h' = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy+x^2) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy+x^2)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy-y^2) & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy-y^2)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
y+2x & x\\
y & x-2y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which means that the transposed matrix $\left(h'\right)^T$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 
y+2x & y\\
x & x-2y
\end{pmatrix}
$. If we then evaluate this matrix at $(3,-3)$ we get
$$
\left(h'\right)^T(3,-3) = \begin{pmatrix} 
-3+2(3) & -3\\
3 & 3-2(-3)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
-3+6 & -3\\
3 & 3+6
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
3 & -3\\
3 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
$$
On the other hand, we see that
$$
h(3,-3) = (3(-3)+3^2, 3(-3) -(-3)^2) = (-9+9, -9-9) = (0,-18)
$$
which tells us that
$$
\left(\nabla f \circ h\right)(3,-3) = \nabla f\left(h(3,-3)\right) = \nabla f\left(0,-18\right) = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\3 \end{pmatrix}
$$
using the convention of the gradient as a *column* vector.

Finally, putting all this together tells us that
$$
\nabla g(3,-3) = \nabla (f \circ h)(3,-3) = \left[\left(h'\right)^T(3,-3)\right] \cdot \left[\left(\nabla f \circ h\right)(3,-3)\right] = \begin{pmatrix} 
3 & -3\\
3 & 9
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\3 \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} -2(3)+3(-3) \\-2(3)+3(9) \end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix} -6-9 \\-6+27 \end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix} -15 \\21 \end{pmatrix} = -15 \boldsymbol{\hat\imath} + 21 \boldsymbol{\hat\jmath}
$$