# How to compute the Hessian of $x \mapsto |x|^{2p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto |x|^2$. Then $\nabla f (x) = 2x$ and $\operatorname{H} f (x) = 2I_d$. For $p \in \mathbb N^*$, let $g_p : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto |x|^{2p}$. Then $g_p = f^p$. By [chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724359/does-there-exist-a-gradient-chain-rule-for-this-case), $\nabla g_p (x) = p f^{p-1} (x) \nabla f (x)$.

My goal is to compute the Hessian matrix of $g_p$.  Every vector is considered as *column* vector. We need the following lemma

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329217/product-rule-for-scalar-vector-product) Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ and $g:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable. Let $\mathrm J f (x)$ be the Jacobian of $f$ at $x$. Let $\nabla g (x)$ be the gradient of $g$ at $x$. Then $\mathrm J (fg)(x) = f (x) (\nabla g (x))^\top + g(x) \mathrm J f (x)$.

It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{H} g_p (x) &= \operatorname{J} (\nabla g_p) (x) \\
&= p \operatorname{J} (f^{p-1} \nabla f) (x)   \\
&= p \big [ \nabla f (x) (\nabla f^{p-1} (x))^\top + f^{p-1} (x)  \operatorname{J} (\nabla f) (x) \big ] \quad \text{by Lemma}\\
&= p \big [ \nabla f (x) (\nabla f^{p-1} (x))^\top + f^{p-1} (x)  \operatorname{H} f (x) \big ] \\
&= 2p \big [ (p-1)f^{p-2} (x) x ( \nabla f (x))^\top + f^{p-1} (x) I_d \big ]  \quad \text{by} \quad \nabla f^{p-1} = \nabla g_{p-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Could you confirm if my above computation is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i, j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, we have
\begin{align}
(\text{Hess }g_p)_{ij} &= \partial_{i}\left(\partial_j (f(x))^p\right)\\
&= \partial_i\left(pf(x)^{p-1}\partial_if(x)\right)\\
&= p\left\{(p-1)f(x)^{p-2}\partial_i f(x)\partial_jf(x) + f(x)^{p-1} \partial^{2}_{ij}f(x)\right\}\\
&= pf(x)^{p-2}\left\{(p-1)\partial_i f(x)\partial_jf(x) + f(x)\partial_{ij}f(x)\right\}
\end{align}
Therefore, we get
$$\text{Hess }g_p = pf^{p-2}\left\{(p-1)[\nabla f]^T [\nabla f] + f \text{Hess }f\right\}.$$

Comment: Ah my bad I didn't see your computation.